# QT application menus don't drop shadow under KDE plasma

Tags: kde, opensuse, qt, plasma5

QT applications, like Qt Creator, menus don't drop shadow under KDE Plasma 5.
I would expect a better integration between KDE and Qt. Even Gtk3/Gnome applications have menus with shadows, but not Qt!?

Any chance I can make QtCreator, and in general any Qt based app, to drop shadows?
Why they don't have them by default?

Screenshot: [image]

Operating System: openSUSE Tumbleweed 20230629
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.6
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.107.0
Qt Version: 5.15.10

qt6-creator version: 11.0.1
Probably using library Qt: 6.5.2

Is there another pure Qt application I can try?